# Autofill a field based in a Data Field in a Table

Tags: ms-access

Hope you're doing well. I have a question in Access. I have an Employee Table with some Fields and 2 of them are 'EndofContract' and the other is 'Condition'.

The EndofContract field is in date format (is the date in which the employee stopped working in the company) and what I want do to is autofill the Condition field with Inactive or Active, based on the date of EndofContract. Basically:
if EndOfContract is blank I want to show Active in Condition;
if EndOfContract has a date that is previous to today's date, I want to show Inactive in Condition

I've tried various different things and the last one was going to Design View » Condition Field » Lookup » RowSource and in the query designer I wrote this condition `IIf(Date()>[EndofContract];"Inactive";"Active")` but it doesn't work. Already tried an AfterUpdate macro but I can't understand how to change the value of every record.

Hope somebody can help me and thank you!

Comment: Well, you shouldn't. All you should do is calculate this value not save. Certainly would not be a Lookup field. If you want to calculate in table, use a Calculated type field - otherwise calculate in query or textbox.

Comment: Already tried both of them but they don't work. When I try to put it in a calculated field it says that the expression can't be used in a calculated column. With a textbox, for some reason, the false part works but the true doesn't, so I autofill every record with Active but not any with Inactive. And with a query it asks me for EnfofContract instead of searching for it in the table

Comment: Turns out Date() is not available for table Calculated field. Expression works for me in query or textbox. Your comment shows field `EnfofContract`, not `EndofContract`, so perhaps you have misspelled in query.

Comment: Maybe I didn't do it right in the textbox. When you have a textbox where do you write the condition? Sorry it this is a silly question!

Comment: Expression in textbox ControlSource property with an = sign: `=IIf(Date()>[EndofContract];"Inactive";"Active") `.

Comment: Is it possible that that property doesn't appear? I opon the table in design view, go to the field and the only thing I can see is Display Control

Comment: A textbox is a control on a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a *textbox* on your form where you display the data.

Assign this expression as its *ControlSource*:

```
=IIf(Nz([EndofContract],Date())>=Date(),"Active","Inactive")
```

or, if semicolon is your list separator:

```
=IIf(Nz([EndofContract];Date())>=Date();"Active";"Inactive")
```

Or, remove the field *Condition* from the table and use a query:

```sql
Select 
   *, IIf(Nz([EndofContract],Date())>=Date(),"Active","Inactive") As Condition
From 
   EmployeeTable
```

If `EndofContract` is text, not a true DateTime value, try this:

```sql
Select 
   *, IIf(Nz(CVDate([EndofContract]),Date())>=Date(),"Active","Inactive") As Condition
From 
   EmployeeTable
```

This requires no updates.

Comment: I will have a form to populate this table but the idea was to do it automatically in the table. Because I'll have to update a lot of records on a mensal base and it's not convenient to update them all in a form

Comment: But this is not what a table is for. Use a query - see extended answer, please.

Comment: I'm trying to use a query but for some reason, it only works in cells that are Null, so it just returns "Active" or "#Error" (in cells that have an EndofContract date). Do you have any idea of why this may be happening? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Perhaps your `EndofContract` is text, and this must be converted to a true date value. See extended answer, please, or (better) change the data type of all "date" fields to _DateTime_.

Comment: It worked! I was using "Date/Time Extended", instead of just "Date/Time". Thank you so much for your help :)